# Compiling existing C++ code with /clr and then calling it from C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have some C++ code:

```
namespace Compute {
  class __declspec(dllexport) IProgressCB {
  public:
    virtual void progress(int percentCompleted) = 0;
  };

  double __declspec(dllexport) compute(IProgressCB *progressCB, ...);
}
```

from which I create "compute.dll" with "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" turned on in Visual Studio 2008.

I want to call this code from C#.

Next I create a C# console application and add compute.dll as a Reference.
Then I try to subclass/implement IProgressCB:

```
public class Progress : Compute.IProgressCB
{
    public void progress(int percentCompleted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(percentCompleted + "% completed.");
    }
}
```

However the autocompletion of VS finds the "Compute" namespace but not any classes or functions inside it!? 
When I try to compile; it complains about IProgressCB not being public.
If I write public before the declaration of IProgressCB it complains about not being able to derive from sealed type 'Compute.IProgressCB' instead.

What am I doing wrong here?
I want to take existing C++ code, do no modifications to it, but compile it with /clrc and then use it from C#. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "do no modifications" to it is possible, but you'll need an intermediary C++/CLI layer to wrap the existing code. C# and other CLR languages can only "see" managed types, that is ref classes, value classes etc. You'll not be able to get away with writing no additional C++ code simply by applying /clr to an extant codebase.

Comment: So /clr offers a way to port existing code from C++ to .net, and not a way to maintain a common codebase in unmanaged C++ that is used from both unmanaged C++ and .net?

Comment: @Andreas: C++/CLI offers a way to use existing code in .NET.  You have to write new C++/CLI code, but that code understands and just works with both .NET and native world, so you don't need to rewrite existing behavior, you can delegate to the existing code.

Comment: In fact to do what Ben suggests (and what I alluded to) you don't even necessarily need to compile the existing code with /CLR at all.

Comment: Exactly, but this is a different strategy: introduce a C++/CLI wrapper around an existing C++ library. After reading your advice (thanks!); this is what I am going to do. However it would be possible to have code with macros inside it that was used both for unmanaged C++ and for managed C++ compiled with /clr. This would be rather messy though. So in my opinion /clr is a way to ease porting from unmanaged C++ to managed C++, whereas a C++/CLI wrapper is a way to use existing unmanaged C++ from managed C++.

Comment: (Here I have used "managed C++" to denote C++/CLI that is running inside .net, not the infamous predecessor to C++/CLI).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly C++-CLI (*the sucessor of Managed Extensions for C++*) is not (like) C++. Visibilty of namespace members is only a small fraction of the difference.

The biggest trip up will be non-deterministic destruction of ref classes.

I suggest

1. Read up on CLR assemblies first
2. Don't think C++ anymore:
3. Grok garbage collection
4. Grok header dependencies, pImpl idom and gcroot<>
5. Now, try a C++-CLI library from scratch to wrap a native library

After <strike>1-2 years of[1]</strike>*ample* experience, you will be able to tell how much work it is to port a native C++ library 1:1 to C++-CLI

[1] -- ok maybe you are a fast learner :)

Comment: Don't you mean C++/CLI rather than Managed C++?

Comment: But they don't mean the same thing.  "Managed C++" has always been used to refer to the aborted and extremely buggy "Managed Extensions for C++" (think `__gc` keyword) which were introduced in VC7.0, a few fixes were made in VC7.1, then entirely abandoned in VC8 when it was realized just how deep the design problems went.  Even if the user doesn't care about the history, encourage use of the right terminology, it'll make communicating with the experts far easier in general.

Comment: Yes I mean C++/CLI, sorry for the confusing choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

`IProgressCB` has to be a managed class to be visible from C#.

```
public ref class IProgressCB
{
    // ...
};
```

Doing this, IProgressCB will work quite differently than it did before, especially the memory management is now completely different.

You can use C++/CLI to write managed wrappers for your existing unmanaged classes, but don't expect that you can use unmanaged C++ classes from C# directly just by adding "/clr" to your compiler switches. Read this article

http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/07/12/Mixing-Native-and-Managed-Types-in-C_2B002B00_.aspx

to get a notion what you have to do to transfer data from one world to the other and vice versa.